# Working with Sqlite database in android

Tags: android, sqlite

If we already have a databse file in .sql format, How can we load this in our android app & use its data?

Comment: [have a look at it/..](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)

Comment: refer this
http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/

Comment: please check it is duplicate question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am giving you the complete code,plz reply if you success

```
public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
private Context mycontext;

private String DB_PATH = "/data/data/gr.peos/databases/";
//private String DB_PATH = mycontext.getApplicationContext().getPackageName()+"/databases/";
private static String DB_NAME = "BLib.sqlite";//the extension may be .sqlite or .db
public SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;
/*private String DB_PATH = "/data/data/"
                        + mycontext.getApplicationContext().getPackageName()
                        + "/databases/";*/

public DataBaseHelper(Context context) throws IOException  {
super(context,DB_NAME,null,1);
this.mycontext=context;
boolean dbexist = checkdatabase();
if(dbexist)
{
    //System.out.println("Database exists");
    opendatabase(); 
}
else
{
    System.out.println("Database doesn't exist");
createdatabase();
}

}

public void createdatabase() throws IOException{
boolean dbexist = checkdatabase();
if(dbexist)
{
    //System.out.println(" Database exists.");
}
else{
    this.getReadableDatabase();
try{
        copydatabase();
    }
    catch(IOException e){
        throw new Error("Error copying database");
    }
}
}
private boolean checkdatabase() {
//SQLiteDatabase checkdb = null;
boolean checkdb = false;
try{
    String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    File dbfile = new File(myPath);
    //checkdb = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath,null,SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    checkdb = dbfile.exists();
}
catch(SQLiteException e){
    System.out.println("Database doesn't exist");
}

return checkdb;
}
private void copydatabase() throws IOException {

//Open your local db as the input stream
InputStream myinput = mycontext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

// Path to the just created empty db
String outfilename = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

//Open the empty db as the output stream
OutputStream myoutput = new FileOutputStream("/data/data/gr.peos/databases/BLib.sqlite");

// transfer byte to inputfile to outputfile
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int length;
while ((length = myinput.read(buffer))>0)
{
    myoutput.write(buffer,0,length);
}

//Close the streams
myoutput.flush();
myoutput.close();
myinput.close();

}

public void opendatabase() throws SQLException
{
//Open the database
String mypath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(mypath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);

}



public synchronized void close(){
if(myDataBase != null){
    myDataBase.close();
}
super.close();
}
//Your methods to insert view contents of database
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [SQLiteOpenHelper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html) for this.
 Refer [Using SQLite Database with Android](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/android/AndroidSQLite.aspx) where explained it clearly with examples.
So you can use   `db.execSQL("sql statements"):`